# Zend framework error Class 'models_News' not found

Tags: zend-framework, model

Model in *aplication/model/newsModel.php*

```
class models_newsModel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{
}
```

Controller in *application\controllers\LoginController.php*

I try create object to model

```
$this->news = new models_newsModel();
```

and get error: *Class 'models_newsModel' not found in C:\wamp\www\sistema\application\controllers\LoginController.php on line 27*

Maybe problem is in my application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
; ADD THE FOLLOWING LINES
;resources.layout.layout = "layout"
;resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create the resource loader ?
You can initialize it in your bootstrap:

```
protected function _initAppAutoload()
{
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH));    
}
```

By default it expects models to be stored under: `application/models/` and named as `Model_*` or `Model_News` in your case. However, if you want you can change models location and naming scheme using `addResourceType` method. Read more [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.autoloading.resources.html)